# Full screen Android phone app doesn't show full screen on Google TV

Tags: android-layout, google-tv

The following simple layout shows full screen on an Android phone, but not on Google TV where it
it shows on only a part of the TV screen (top half and middle third) and there's some sort of wallpaper on the rest of it (just saying in case it's not that usual, documentation is rare as far as I could see).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
        <com.orb.androidplayer.view.VideoSurfaceView 
            android:id="@+id/video_view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem isn't coming fom the video widget either, it's the 
same if I remove it, add a TextView instead, try fill/match parent, etc...

Can anyone assist me with identifying the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add element min SDK in AndroidManifest.xml
Exp: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`

Comment: This! Thanks, that's exactly what I needed, can't believe it. Do you know why it is that way? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your application or activity theme to

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: That's not it I'm afraid... I'm currently trying to copy one element after the other a google template that does seem to fit, but that's a big one, guess I'll tell when I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<supports-screens/>` tag from the AndroidManifest.